# Using function inside Handlebars Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, bing-maps, handlebars.js

I'm using a handlebars template and have successfully registered a helper. However, I want to do a $.getJSON and make some results from that ajax request show in the template.

Here is my javascript code (written in coffee)

```
      Handlebars.registerHelper('getNearestAddressFromPoint',(lat,lon) ->
    console.log("in register helper")
    bingURL = 'http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + lat + ','+ lon + '?&key=' + bingMapsKey + '&jsonp=?'
    $.getJSON(bingURL,@pointSuccess))


  pointSuccess:(data)=>
    tooltipAddr = $(@el).find("#tooltipAddr")
    address = data.resourceSets[0].resources.name
    $(tooltipAddr).text(address)
    console.log("hello")
```

This jquery.text is not being run, and neither is the console.log, however "in register helper" is being logged.

This could be because the helper is returning $.getJSON as a function, because in my template [object Object] is being shown and it is displaying the function as an object. I want it so that the results of the call back are being returned, or that the callback is being called

Answer (score 0):

The clue is at the end of the url: `'&jsonp=?'`. This indicates the use of JSONP, which is a way of using JSON cross-domain. So instead of `$.getJSON` you will have to use something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: bingURL,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    success: @pointSuccess
});
```

Remove the `'&jsonp=?'` on your url and let jQuery handle it.